# Unrendered Symfony2 form fields impede form validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony, hidden-field

I have a list of users which can be active or not.

For all users I create a choice field with the role a user can have.

During the rendering I render only the fields for the active users.

Once the form display is finished I use

> {{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}

to avoid the unnecessary fields to be rendered. Those underendered fields impede the validation of the form.
I tried to create a hidden choice field but failed.

Here's the relevant code:

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()->getForm(); //create empty form
foreach ($HRsInThisProject as $key => $HR)
    {
        $form->add('roleOf_'.$key, 'choice', array('choices'   => $rolesListForForm,'required'  => true,'data' => $HR['role'], 'label' => false, ));
    }
$form->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Save'));
```

In my twig I have:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>User ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Role</td>
    <td>Started</td>
</tr>

{% for key, HR in HRs %}
    {% if HR.is_active %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ key }}</td>
        <td>{{ HR.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ form_row(form['roleOf_' ~ key]) }}</td>
        <td>{{ HR.started_at|date('Y-m-d H:i:s') }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</table>
<br>
{{ form_row(form.save) }}
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

This is what I'd like to have (notice that only relevant fields are displayed):
[image]

If on the other hand if I use:

> {{ form_end(form) }}

Then the code works but I see unnnecessary fields displayed:

[image]

I also tried to make the unnecessary fields as non required, but the problem persists.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that field from being rendered you have to remove it from your `FormType` and assign a default value for that field in the entity as

```
Class User {

     protected $unnecessary = "Some Value";

}
```

Or you can use `FormEvents` to assign a default value for that property

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html

Or you can render the field as hidden

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/hidden.html

**The bottom line is once you add a property to the `FormType` that field will be rendered for sure.**

Comment: I managed to solve it by declaring "{% do form['roleOf_' ~ key].setRendered %}" for each of the unnecessary fields. It works like a charm but...is this the right way?

Comment: If your form is still validating when you set the `roleOfX` fields to being rendered then they wouldn't have been the problem. I would hazard a guess that the actual issue was in the that you didn't render the csrf token (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#csrf-protection) which would be rendered either in the catch all `form_rest()/form_end(form)` or directly using `form_row(form._token)` (if using the default field name of `_token`).

Comment: @SergioNegri i wonder why you add a field to FormType and then change the status to rendered what is the point of all of this? if you don't want it in the form simply don't add it to the FormType.

Comment: @laith.ar : there are cases where it might make sense, but in this case you are right, I was mixing the client side and the server side behavior. What I'll do is always rendering the fields, and then client side showing them or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

If the field of a form is not rendered, then his value will be sent as `NULL`.
So if you already set a value for this field, it will be nullified.